# Use greaterThan on Date from another table with parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am building an app with ionic and parse.com (using JS). 
I have three tables :

```
 User(username,password);
 Question(questionStr, endAt(date), user(pointer to User));
 QuestionShare(question (pointer to Question), responseStr, user(pointer to User));
```

What I would like is to select all QuestionShare where questionShare.user = Parse.User.current() AND Question.endAt > a certain date.

I tried :

```
 var QuestionShare = Parse.Object.extend("QuestionShare");
 var query = new Parse.Query(QuestionShare);
 query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
 query.include("question");
 query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("question.endAt", new Date());
```

I hope this is possible, if not, I will have to filter the results myself with JS.